# How to write reusable javascript function with cypress commands

Tags: javascript, cypress

I am new to cypress and testing. I need to get the visible text from an element in cypress also store it inside a variable. with selenium we can easily get element value using getText() method. But in cypress we need to use a code like below.

HTML element:

```
<div class='myClass'>this is text</div>
```

javascript reusable function

```
function getText(byclassName)
    {
     let campaign;
        cy.get(byclassName)
        .invoke('text').then((text) => {
          campaign = text
          cy.log('campaign',  text)
          return text          
        })
    }
```

then my cypress test goes like this

```
 it('finds the role', () => {
   const elementText= getText('.myClass')//fails
    cy.log('campaign',  getText('.myClass'))
 }) // it fails
```

Please tell me what am I missing here? I want to write a generic function which returns me the visible text from div element and also store it or log it in console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are returning the value inside your Promise function. Promises however can't return values, they can only resolve with a value. This means you'll have to use Promises throughout your code like this:

```
function getText(byclassName) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        cy.get(byclassName).invoke('text')
            .then(campaign => {
                cy.log('campaign', campaign);
                resolve(campaign);
            });
    });
}

it('finds the role', function () {
    cy.visit(...);

    return getText('.myClass').then(elementText => {
        cy.log('campaign', elementText);

        expect(elementText).to.equal(...);
    });
})
```

Comment: still does not get value from getText function

Comment: I just updated my answer which is now working fine for me.

Comment: is there a way to just compare text of two elements like const var1=getText('.myClass');
const var2=getText('.myRole'); it does not allow me to compare var1 wth var2

Answer (score 3):

You can also write this as a [custom command](https://docs.cypress.io/api/cypress-api/custom-commands.html), which I find to be a bit easier to read and being able to control what's logged to the command log is a bonus.

Here is a custom command I'm using in a bunch of our tests to get text from an element.  It gets text differently than what you are doing - I have found using `invoke()` pretty finicky, maybe it's the way our app is designed.  If you want to get text using `invoke()` you can do that as well inside of a custom command.

```
Cypress.Commands.add("text", { prevSubject: "element" }, subject => {
  return cy.wrap(subject, { log: false }).then($el => {
    var text = $el.get(0).text();

    Cypress.log({
      name: "text",
      message: "",
      consoleProps() {
        return {
          yielded: text,
        };
      },
    });

    return text;
  });
});

it('finds the role', function () {
    cy.visit(...);

    return cy.get('.myClass').text().then(elementText => {
        cy.log('campaign', elementText);

        expect(elementText).to.equal(...);
    });
})
```